# Можно ли получить имя процесса текущего активного окна?

Tags: c#

Я хочу написать для себя простенький сервис для отслеживания того, с какими программами я работаю в течении дня и сколько времени на них трачу.

Как я представляю работу такой программы? У меня на ПК в фоне должна работать программа, которая будет мониторить текущее активное окно и то, сколько оно активно. На сервер будут отправляться данные такого типа:

```
Процесс       Был активен
phpstrom.exe  3600
```

Ну и далее эти данные будут выводиться в виде графиков.

Вопрос - можно ли реализовать это на C#? К сожалению, у меня нет опыта разработки софта под Windows, по этому, я понятия не имею, что мне нужно использовать. Не могли бы вы подсказать технологию и пример того, как можно получить имя процесса текущего активного окна?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То что вы хотите можно сделать с использованием winapi функций. Вам понадобятся две: [GetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx), [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx)

По ссылкам можно найти описание параметров функций и в какой DLL-библиотеке они находятся.
Их описание нужно объявить в c# следующим образом:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 public static extern UInt32 GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hwnd, ref Int32 pid);
```

После этого ими можно пользоваться. Первая функция получает дескриптор активного окна, вторая - получает идентификатор процесса по дескриптору окна. В пространстве `System.Diagnostics` есть класс `Process`, с помощью которого можно получить данные о процессе. Ну как минимум заголовок окна. Вот пример использования:

```
IntPtr h = GetForegroundWindow();
int pid = 0;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(h, ref pid);
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
Console.Write("pid: {0}; window: {1}", pid, p.MainWindowTitle);
```

Answer (score 3):

Конкретно такой задачи я не решал, но судя по всему вам нужно:
`GetForegroundWindow()` - для получения хэндла активного окна;
`GetWindowThreadProcessId()` - для получения PIDа по хэндлу;
`GetProcessImageFileName()` - для получения имени бинарника по хэндлу процесса.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать =)